# iOS XMPP how to fetch roster without calling connect method

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

I am working on XMPP based project. Currently, I my application fetch rosterlist with calling `connect`method when we enter in `chatview controller` is it possible to fetch online and ofline buddylist without calling `connect` method. currently i get rosterlist like this. (just like chatsecure opensource)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
  {
         UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44)];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
 //  [[self appDelegate]goOnline];
if ( [[self appDelegate] connect])
{
    titleLabel.text = [[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID] bare];
} else
{
    titleLabel.text = @"No JID";
}

[titleLabel sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. To be able to interact with an XMPP server, you need to have a session opened and be authenticated.